# Python+ExtJs4. Cannot execute js script

Tags: python, extjs, flask

I am new in ExtJs and python. I wanted to try some staff in Flask + ExtJs.
I have created a template for view that I wanted to use in Flask. It worked well.
After I tried to use ExtJs in my template. There is an example in sencha docs hot to get started. This is how my template "index.html" looks like:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ title }} - microblog</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/ext-all.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js" />
  </head>
  <body>
      Hello, {{ user.nickname}}!
  </body>
</html>
```

However, it does not work. I am getting messages 404 not found for "ext/ext-all.js" and "ext/resources/css/ext-all.css". It seems strange since these files exist in fact.
My folder structer is the following:

App

```
 templates
    ext
    index.html
    app.js
```

...

Is there anyone, who knows the reason of such behaviour?

Comment: The reason for a 404 is trivial: The server does not serve the file. Reasons are depending on the webserver you use. Open Chrome developer console, Network tab. Usually the server will return additional details with the the 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your files are in the wrong place. Static files belong in the `static` folder, not `templates`.

Also, using relative URLs in your templates will lead to problems. Fortunately, Flask provides `url_for` to help with this very thing.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='ext/resources/css/ext-all.css') }}" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='ext/ext-all.js') }}" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='app.js') }}" />
```

Comment: yes, it works now, thanks.
But we need {{ and without '%' symbol

Comment: 304 isn't an error. It "not modified." That means your browser already has the most up-to-date version of the file. (And I fixed the delimiters, thanks.)

Comment: I am getting 304 messgae now

Comment: Again, not an error. It's a good thing. You may want to read up on [what the status code means](https://httpstatuses.com/304).

Comment: Thanks! It has helped.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it.